# Отображение view элемента в alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Имеется следующий layout файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_healthLayout_Pressure"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/textView_ArterPressure"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_healthLayout_Pressure_upperValue"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberSigned" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_healthLayout_SLASH"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
                android:text="/"
                android:textSize="40dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_healthLayout_Pressure_downValue"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberSigned" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_healthLayout_puls"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="@string/textView_Puls"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_healthLayout_puls"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberSigned"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_healthLayout_healthState"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="@string/textView_healthState"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                />
            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton_healthState_1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="@string/NUMBER_1" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton_healthState_2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/NUMBER_2" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton_healthState_3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/NUMBER_3" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton_healthState_4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/NUMBER_4" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton_healthState_5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/NUMBER_5" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton_healthState_6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/NUMBER_6" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton_healthState_7"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/NUMBER_7" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton_healthState_8"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/NUMBER_8" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton_healthState_9"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/NUMBER_9" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton_healthState_10"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/NUMBER_10" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

в Main.java при нажатии на определённую кнопку данный layout-файл должен высвечиваться в alertdialog:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View viewHealth = inflater.inflate(R.layout.health,null);
ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
ad.setView(viewHealth);
ad.show();
```

Проблема в том, что при запуске приложения при нажатии на данную кнопку высвечивается просто пустое окно вместо layout-элемента. Не могу понять, в чём причина.

Comment: Просмотрите данный урок, возможно все проясниться:
https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/126-urok-65-dialogi-alertdialog-kastomizatsija.html

Answer (score 0):

Если вы вызываете диалоговое окно в Main классе, откуда у вас context? Попробуйте вызвать так:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.health, null);
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertDialog.setView(view);
AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
alert.show();
```

Comment: Добавил: не помогло.

Comment: Если вы используете в Main классе, каким образом у вас там появился context? Обновил ответ

Comment: В самом начале после объявления класса объявлена переменная context типа Context, которой при вызове onCreate() присвоено значение MainActivity.this